# How to fix SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to pull data from a json file and display it in a table on my web page. The json file is updated dynamically with data about movies from an api. The function that I am using right now is giving a syntax error about needing a name.

I have tried naming the function but so far nothing has worked. I'm new to web development so if it's an obvious answer I'm sorry.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Furby</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href="static/layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
  $(function() {
  var table = document.getElementById('userdata');
  for(var i = table.rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
  {
    table.deleteRow(i);
  }
  $.getJSON('static/movies.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.movie, function(i, f) {
      var url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/" + f.url;
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<img id = 'url_img' >" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
      document.getElementById('url_img').src = url;
      document.getElementById('url_img').id = url;
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body id="top">
  <div id="pageintro" class="hoc clear">
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
    <div class="flexslider basicslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <article>
            <h3 class="heading">Find A Movie</h3>
            <p>Search from thousands of online movies!</p>
            <footer>
              <form class="group" method="post" action="search" onsubmit="function();">
                <fieldset>
                  <legend>Search:</legend>
                  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search Here&hellip;" name="search">
                  <button class="fa fa-sign-in" type="submit" title="Submit"><em>Submit</em></button>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </footer>
          </article>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="profile">
              <table id= "userdata" border="2">
                <thead>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Cover</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
  </div>
  <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
<script src="static/layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/layout/scripts/jquery.backtotop.js"></script>
<script src="static/layout/scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<script src="static/layout/scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code below will update my table with the movie titles and images once but I have to do a hard refresh on the page to get it to update. I assume it's the name error that is preventing it from running this code every time I search a movie.

[image]

EDIT: Added more relevant code. Sorry this is my first time posting.

Comment: I don't see any function statements here. What exactly is the error?

Comment: Also, what's the relevance of Python?

Comment: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name is the exact error in the console. Sorry about python I am using flask to run the server and forgot to mention that in the question. The error is appearing on line 1 with <!DOCTYPE html>. Everything I have seen is suggesting that either indention or brackets are messed up but I don't see where.

Comment: line number and  posting the error will help . may be you should try removing this js code and  see !!!

Comment: @RollickBoon If the errors is appearing on line 1, you haven't shown the relevant code. You may have what you intended to be a top level IIFE, and forgot the wrapping and calling parenthesis?

Comment: "*I assume it's the name error that is preventing it from running this code every time I search a movie.*"  Disregarding any errors you may have, there is no logic here to repeat this logic when a "search" happens.  All you have here is a one and done json lookup and table population.

Comment: `onsubmit="function();">` is not valid

Comment: What is the valid way to call this as a function then?

Comment: You have to place your code **under** jQuery Library; or to place the jQuery Library **before** your code.  because your code use jQuery, this implies that the jQuery was loaded before him

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that? I am new to jQuery and I don't understand.

Comment: I made un example below, and you use 2 jQuery version, that'is also wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inline event listener from the form.

```
<form class="group" method="post" action="search">
```

Name your function

```
function performSearch () {
  var table = document.getElementById('userdata');
  for (var i = table.rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    table.deleteRow(i);
  }
  $.getJSON('static/movies.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.movie, function(i, f) {
      var url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/" + f.url;
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<img id = 'url_img' >" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
      document.getElementById('url_img').src = url;
      document.getElementById('url_img').id = url;
    });
  });
}
```

Call your function on page load.

```
$(function(){
    performSearch();
});
```

And setup the form to perform the search on submit.

```
$(function(){
    performSearch();

    $('.group[action="search"]').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        performSearch();
    });
});
```

Comment: Will the the last two jQuery functions go in the same script tag as perfomSearch()?

Comment: All the script will go in the same script tag.  The script tag will have the function definition, followed by the `$(function(){})` containing your inital search and the submit event listener for future searches.  If you want, the performSearch definition can go in the `$(function(){})` as well, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: The name error is gone now but the table is still not updating each time I search. I still have to ctrl+shift+r to update the page to reflect my most recent search results. It might be a problem with the even listener as I have not set one up before. I copied exactly what you have.

Comment: You also have to fix the issue of the multiple jQuery includes in your page, or put this script after your last jQuery include so it is not destroyed.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the search result problem by forcing my web page to not use cached files when it refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) You have 2 jQuery Lib, that wrong,  you need only one also check versions

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
. . . 
<script src="static/layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2) your HTML table is not valid : you forget placing forget `<tr> .... </tr>`

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Cover</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  id="userdata-tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
```

I also place the `id="userdata-tbody"` on the `<tbody>` otherwise you also delete your `<thead>` row

so place your jQuery lib before the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Furby</title>
  <link href="static/layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <script src="static/layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/layout/scripts/jquery.backtotop.js"></script>
  <script src="static/layout/scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
  <script src="static/layout/scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function () {
        var tableUserData = document.getElementById('userdata-tbody');
...

        for(var i = tableUserData.rows.length; i--;)
        {
          tableUserData.deleteRow(i);
        }  
  ...

      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
...
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Cover</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  id="userdata-tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
...

</body>
</html>
```